# task.isSuccessful() is always giving false in signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I've created a register user page and a login page. Users are gettings registered and they are visible in firebase console but when I log in, it always says invalid password.

Below is my sign in code:

```
private void loginUser(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            try {
                                throw task.getException();
                            }

                            catch (FirebaseAuthEmailException e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            catch (FirebaseAuthException e){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    public void  updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
        if(user != null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"You Signed In successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"You Didn't signed in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue.And I made these mistakes.

1.Make sure that you enable sign in from Email/Password.

[image]

2.Make sure you use the latest version of FirebaseAuth in your gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
```

Comment: The code you have given seems ok.Its probably something else...like internet permissions or something with the configuration of firebase auth in the console...

Comment: I've already added this is manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. I updated some dependencies in gradle file and also there was a small error/warning in my manifest file saying login activity xml file has no body. So i switched from `<activity>...</activity>` to `<activity ... />`  and now everything's working.